# Showing a function is odd

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetry

I have this equation:

$$ f(x) = \frac{2x^2+3}{x-2} $$

and I have to prove it has half-turn symmetry around the point (2,8). I know that for a function to have half-turn symmetry, it needs to have the property:

$$ f(-x) = -f(x) $$

So I need to substitute (2,8) into the equation, so

$$ -\frac{2(x-2)^2+3}{(x-2)-2}+8 = \frac{2(2-x)^2+3}{(2-x)-2}+8 $$

But after solving it out and/or graphing it, I don't get equality. In desmos, the two graphs are reflections of each other, in the line $x=2$, but they're not equal. What am I doing wrong?

edit:

Updated equation, but I'm still not getting it. After simplifying I reached $$-\frac{2x^2-8x+11}{x-4} = \frac{2x^2-8x+11}{-x} $$ but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Wow.... I misread the function, it's $2x^2$ not $2x^3$. I'm really stupid.

Comment: So can you update your work with the corrected question?

Comment: ok, i updated it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Symmetry w.r.t. the point $(a,b)$ translates as
$$f(2a-x)=2b-f(x).$$
Can you check it?

*Justification:*

If the  points $M=(x, f(x))$ and $M'=(x', f(x'))$ are symmetric w.r.t. $I=(a,b)$, this means $I$ is the midpoint of $[MM']$, i.e.
$$a=\frac{x+x'}2, \quad b=\frac{f(x)+f(x')}2,$$
whence
$$x'=2a-x,\quad f(x')=f(2a-x)=2b-f(x).$$

Comment: That works, but I haven't learned this identity. Why does this work?

Comment: I'll justify in a moment, but it's at the high school level.